# How can a package hierarchy contain another package class

Tags: java, package

I am not sure about the `java.lang` Hierarchy. How can it contain `java.security.Permission` class? [Follow the link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/package-tree.html) and search for `java.security.Permission`.

Comment: How interesting, I've never noticed that! Now I'm curious too. I hope someone who knows is able to answer this.

Comment: It might be because [java.lang.RuntimePermission](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimePermission.html) `extends BasicPermission` which is of `java.security.permission`, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It doesn't contain that class. It's there just to show that `java.lang.RuntimePermission` is derived from `java.security.BasicPermission`, which is derived from `java.security.Permission`.

The class contained in the `java.lang` package is `java.lang.RuntimePermission`, but that webpage shows you the full class hierarchy, even if those class are not contained in the `java.lang` package.